# Error running --eval mongodb command

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I tried to run javascript (js) file to get shard's config server information, it runs fine in mongo shell but as result is too large to analyse on command prompt, i tried to save the output in a file using below mentioned command

```
F:\git\bits-n-pieces\scripts> mongo --shell wts.js aggutil.js \
--eval "printjson(wts('config192'))" > out.log 
  MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4 connecting to: test 
  type "help" for help 
  2015-02-16T15:48:34.088+0530 
  ReferenceError: wts is not defined
```

As i am trying to load as well run js function concurrently, it is not running, Could anyone provide a approach to run the function of js and save the output to file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `--shell` with the redirection `>` as this will redirect the shell  to stdout and the program will appear to hang.

```
mongo test.js test1.js --eval "var t = 900" > out.txt
```

Plus, it looks like something is wrong with your javascript files since it's complaining that `wts` isn't defined. Did you paste in exactly what you see when you run that command? If I use a command like yours

```
mongo --shell test.js test1.js --eval "var t = 900" > out.txt
```

I get no output at all because of the stdout redirect. If I take out the `>`, I get

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.6
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
loading file: test.js
loading file: test1.js
>
```

What version of the shell are you running?